# Port problems installing XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, port

Hello I am installing XAMPP and I am having a problem with MySQL port 3306.

I have used the control panel config my.ini and changed the port settings to 3307 and it is still showing the following error:

> 22:48:55  [mysql]  Problem detected!
>   22:48:55  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MYSQL57"!
>
> 22:48:55  [mysql]  MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
>   22:48:55  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
>   22:48:55  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: Uninstall the other MYSQL Server you have installed on your system. **After backing up any databases of course** And then set `my.ini` back to using port 3306

Answer (score 0):

on Windows+R write cmd and press enter

on command line write:

netstat -nap tcp

and press enter, LISTENING are port used, search for 3307

for view name process use (execute how administrator):

netstat -nabop tcp